# Real-time data APIs

Tags: api, big-data

I've recently started building a home project in Java for which I need lots of data (around 100 events per second). The problem, of course, is that I can't seem to find any publicly available APIs I could use.

The only source I found is meetup.com's RSVP that can deliver around 150 events per minute.

Does anyone know of open API services that deliver 100 events per second?

Comment: Suggestion: Get a twitter developer account, try the twitter streaming APIs (not the REST apis) and search for a popular topic e.g. #trump, or all tweets in english language. writing to local file gave me 100MB-1 GB/hour but I didn't want more

Comment: @knb can you please post this is an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Here you can find tons of APIs:

https://www.programmableweb.com/category/all/apis

You also have a filter for *streaming APIs*:

https://www.programmableweb.com/category/streaming/apis?category=20253

Answer (score 1):

Use Unigraph's data streaming API, it will return you thousands of items per second. Here's how to set it up: https://github.com/unigraph/docs/wiki/Streaming

For now just run this sample query in your terminal, to see the amount of results you can get per second:

```
curl -X POST -H 'X-Unigraph-API-Key: [YOUR_API_KEY]' -d 'query UK @stream { node(uid: "1291") {label }}' http://u01.unigraph.rocks/query
```

Hope this helps your project!